# Understanding TF-IDF scores

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I am trying to understand how tf and idf scores are calculated when we vectorize a text document usign `TfidfVectorizer`.

I am understanding how tf-idf ranks in 2 ways, which I am writing below.

1. tf = ranking a single word based on how often it repeats in this document and idf = ranking the same word on how often it gets repeated in a built-in 'database-like' collection in scikit learn where almost all possible words are collected. Here I assume this built in database to be the corpus.
2. tf = ranking a single work how often it repeats in the line in the document which is currently being read by tfidfvectorize and idf = ranking based on how many times it is repeated in the entire document that is being vectorized.

Could someone please explain if any of my understanding is correct? And if not please correct what is wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact answer is in [sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#tfidf-term-weighting):

> ... the **term frequency**, the number of times a term occurs in a given document, is multiplied with **idf** component, which is computed as
>
> `idf(t) = log[(1 + n_d) / (1+df(d,t))] + 1`,
>
> where `n_d` is the total number of documents, and `df(d,t)` is the number of documents that contain term `t`.

So your first item is correct about the **tf**, but both items miss the point that **idf** is the inverse *document* frequency, so it's the ratio of the number of *documents* (all documents vs documents that contain the term at least once). The formula is taking the log of the ratio to make the ratio function more "flat", and can be adjusted by the class arguments.

Comment: According to the formula for idf(t), if I have only one document that I'm vectorizing, will the idf(t) score be 1 for all the words?

Comment: Yes, Idf doesn't make sense if there's just one document. The exact value may be different, depending on the formula, it'll be the same for all terms

Comment: So, if I use Tfidfvectorizer for a single document, then common words like 'he' or 'and' will have high scores. Am I correct?

Comment: Correct. You need to use a lot of documents